# Compass (SASS) not adding vendor-prefixes to linear-gradient

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, gradient, linear-gradients

I'm working on an AngularJS project using the AngularJS generator for Yeoman.

I installed Compass as a gem because I couldn't find/figure out an appropriate compass bower package.

Various compass mixins I'm using work fine; expect the linear-gradient one; it seems to only pass-through my content and not modify it with vendor-specific prefixes:

SASS:

```
@import "compass";

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: .2em solid #fff;
    @include border-radius(.5em);
    @include background-image(linear-gradient(top, #000, #fff));
}
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: .2em solid #fff;
  -o-border-radius: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #000000, #ffffff);
}
```

As you can see, linear-gradient is being passed-through without any vendor prefixes (but border radius is getting an Opera one) and thus won't work in Chrome. I've checked and rechecked and this is exactly how the Compass documentation explains it.

What am I doing wrong?

```
bootstrap-sass-official#3.1.1+2
compass (0.12.6, 0.12.4, 0.12.3)
compass-core (1.0.0.alpha.19)
compass-import-once (1.0.4)
compass-normalize (1.5)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out; I saw a a lot of similar problems on here and initially none of them addressed "my" issue.

It's apparently because autoprefixer (which is bundled/enabled by default with the angular generator) was stripping out prefixes.

The default setting for it in gruntfile.js is "last 1 version". This breaks it for Safari and Chrome (and as far as I know, I'm running the latest).

Setting it to "last 2 versions" fixed it for me.

More at: https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer#browsers